# Out-of-memory Exception by loading large amount of data with entity framework 6

Tags: .net-4.0, entity-framework-6, out-of-memory

I have an issue with loading a lot amount of data with Entity Framework.

I have around 20 tables that are linked together, and I need, at the beginning of the process, to load all the data with navigation properties populated for futher calculation purpose.

I declare my context with a using statement and load all the datas.

My problem is that the memory goes to 900 MB at the peak of the loading (for one example, it can be more, generating Out-of-memory exception at the middle of the loading). Just after the close of the using statement, the memory is 370MB, my data are loaded.

LazyLoading is set to false, and I am using AsNoTracking() on each LinqToSQL request.

I am wondering why there is such a big difference during the loading process, and if I can avoid it.

Does anyone have an idea of how i can reduce the memory used ?

Thanks by advance.

EDIT :

Adding code example (the rest of the loading is similar, with other objects) :

```
    using (var ctx = OptiviaContextFactory.Create())
            {
                CurrentEtude = ctx.Etudes.AsNoTracking().Include("Offre").FirstOrDefault(_ => _.EtudeID.Equals(etudeid));
                CurrentEtude.StatutOffre = AuthentificationInfo.Instance.GeneralCache.CacheRef.ListStatutOffre.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.StatutOffreID == CurrentEtude.StatutOffreID);

                if (CurrentEtude != null)
                {

                    ctx.VersionVariantes.AsNoTracking().Where(_ => _.EtudeID.Equals(etudeid)).ToList();

                    ctx.CoefficientClasses.AsNoTracking().Where(_ => _.VersionVariante.EtudeID.Equals(etudeid)).ToList();
                    ctx.CoefficientGroupes.AsNoTracking().Where(_ => _.VersionVariante.EtudeID.Equals(etudeid)).ToList();
                    ctx.CoefficientSousTraitants.AsNoTracking().Where(_ => _.VersionVariante.EtudeID.Equals(etudeid)).ToList();
                    ctx.RabaisMajorationDevis.AsNoTracking().Where(_ => _.VersionVariante.EtudeID.Equals(etudeid)).ToList();
                    ctx.Arrondis.AsNoTracking().Where(_ => _.VersionVariante.EtudeID.Equals(etudeid)).ToList();
```

Comment: Show the relevant code including the LINQ query

Comment: Hello Tim, I have edited my original post. Thanks

Comment: Side-note: your null-check is redundant because you would get a `NullReferenceException` at `CurrentEtude.StatutOffre` anyway.

Comment: Well, all your `ToList` calls create lists with all the data matching the `Where` condition. Do you really have to have it in memory? Maybe it would be sufficient to use a lazy-load approach and/or to process them one at a time(therefore remove `ToList` and use a `foreach`-loop to process them).

Comment: I need all those data for calculation purpose just after the loading. It's part of an optimization project, the paradigm is to load everything at the start and have no further loading after. (Thanks for the side note ;) )

Comment: Best place to calculate is in the database, so that would be a good optimization ;)

Comment: Well the point of my optimisation is to move business logic from the DB to .NET client. Calculation are 30 time faster in .NET, due to DB limitation (SQL Server Express) and functionnal complexity. My app is now a lot faster. I just want to see if I can fix this memory issue.